# Why is Bootloader not behaving like it should?

Tags: html, visual-studio-2019

im trying to make a nav bar for my website project, but it isn't behaving as i wan't it to.

[Im trying to get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhnVA.png)

[But i get this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0abA.png)

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and i am trying to get this code to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Jogge - Home</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <header class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1 class="col-sm-8">Jogge</h1>
            <nav class="col-sm-4">
            <p>Test 1</p>
            <p>Test 2</p>
            </nav>
        </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your code as text instead of an image?

Comment: Yeah of course! I'm new to the site and need to get the basics down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider using [Bootstrap's build in nav bar functionality](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)

However, to fix it as it currently is:
The issue is that you have two columns right now - one with your name and one with the two links. Here is one example of a way to fix this, but I really don't recommend it and would suggest you use bootstrap's built in functionality:

```
    <header class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1 class="col-sm-8">Jogge</h1>
            <p class="col-sm-2">Test 1</p>
            <p class="col-sm-2">Test 2</p>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: No problem! Have a great day.